# Is it possible to make Nginx listen to different ports?

Tags: linux, nginx, virtual-machines, azure

I created one Nginx with one Linux Azure VM, is it possible to make nginx listen to different ports so that when I change the port number, the content would be different. I found there would be a collision if I created two or more ports related to HTTP on VM. Can anyone help me with that?

Answer (score 146, accepted):

Yes, it is.

What you probably want is multiple "server" stanzas, each with a different port, but possibly (probably?) the same server_name, serving the "different" content appropriately within each one, maybe with a different document root in each server.

Full documentation is here:
http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html

Example:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  example.org  www.example.org;
    root         /var/www/port80/
}

server {
    listen       81;
    server_name  example.org  www.example.org;
    root         /var/www/port81/
}
```

Comment: It's annoying that one can't do `listen 80 81;` isn't it? Oh well...

Comment: @MattFletcher It is possible to do something similar, see Felix's comment: http://serverfault.com/a/755791/308219

Comment: I have to do this with IP address instead of domain name, I have created 2 files in `sites-available` but it is not working in my case.

Comment: is "server_name" required?

Comment: /var/www/port80 would mean example.com/port80 right?

Comment: No, with the configuration above the content in /var/www/port80 would be at http://example.org/ (no path suffix, implied port 80).  The content in /var/www/port81 would be at http://example.org:81/

Comment: @MattFletcher you can have multiple listen directives in a server declaration, so listen 80; listen 81;

Answer (score 280):

You can also do the following:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen 8000;
    server_name example.org;
    root /var/www/;
}
```

Comment: This is great. In particular, being able to change the server config in only one server context seems far superior than risking changing one and leaving the other unchanged...

Comment: This does not answer the question asked by @billcyz. He asked for different ports and *different content*. This answer gives different ports with the *same content*.

Comment: @Krishnendu: "much more convenient"? more convenient than what? This doesn't answer the OP question. In that case, both :80 and :8000 point to same content. OP asked explicitly "when I change the port number, the content would be different". So, post from Craig Miskell answers much better to the question than this one

Comment: @cedbeu: Yes you are right in context of the question asked Craig Miskell answer is more appropriate. I was looking for the other solution where I need to serve same content on multiple port, this was the exactly what I needed. Again for given question asked other ans is more appropriate, Sorry if I mislead some one, It was a honest mistake from my side.

Comment: @Krishnendu no problem :) everything clarified now

Comment: The specific question was to serve different content on different ports, this answer does not achieve that.