# Why is nginx serving http2, or is it?

Tags: nginx, virtualhost, configuration, http2

Been trying to get http2 going on my nginx server, and I'm confused about some things. I've looked around here and around the web, but I did not find exactly what I'm looking for, or it's answered using outdated information from back when it was still not "released".

I have working nginx server, using vhosts. It has the http_v2 module

```
me@server:/etc/nginx$ sudo nginx -V | grep http2
nginx version: nginx/1.10.3
built with OpenSSL 1.1.0f  25 May 2017
TLS SNI support enabled
configure arguments: --with-cc-opt='-g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/nginx-2tpxfc/nginx-1.10.3=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2' --with-ld-opt='-Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now' --prefix=/usr/share/nginx --conf-path=/etc/nginx/nginx.conf --http-log-path=/var/log/nginx/access.log --error-log-path=/var/log/nginx/error.log --lock-path=/var/lock/nginx.lock --pid-path=/run/nginx.pid --modules-path=/usr/lib/nginx/modules --http-client-body-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/body --http-fastcgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/fastcgi --http-proxy-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/proxy --http-scgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/scgi --http-uwsgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/uwsgi --with-debug --with-pcre-jit --with-ipv6 --with-http_ssl_module --with-http_stub_status_module --with-http_realip_module --with-http_auth_request_module --with-http_v2_module --with-http_dav_module --with-http_slice_module --with-threads --with-http_addition_module --with-http_geoip_module=dynamic --with-http_gunzip_module --with-http_gzip_static_module --with-http_image_filter_module=dynamic --with-http_sub_module --with-http_xslt_module=dynamic --with-stream=dynamic --with-stream_ssl_module --with-mail=dynamic --with-mail_ssl_module --add-dynamic-module=/build/nginx-2tpxfc/nginx-1.10.3/debian/modules/nginx-auth-pam --add-dynamic-module=/build/nginx-2tpxfc/nginx-1.10.3/debian/modules/nginx-dav-ext-module --add-dynamic-module=/build/nginx-2tpxfc/nginx-1.10.3/debian/modules/nginx-echo --add-dynamic-module=/build/nginx-2tpxfc/nginx-1.10.3/debian/modules/nginx-upstream-fair --add-dynamic-module=/build/nginx-2tpxfc/nginx-1.10.3/debian/modules/ngx_http_substitutions_filter_module
```

(not sure how to highlight the "--with-http_v2_module" in a codeblock)

One of my vhosts has a working ssl (using letsencrypt).

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  example.com;
    return       301 http://www.example.com$request_uri;
}

server {
    server_name www.example.com;
    access_log /log/example.com/access.log;
    error_log /log/example.com/error.log;
    root /www/www.example.com/public;

    client_max_body_size 100M;

    index  index.php;

    location / {
        # my location config there ...
    }

    listen 80; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.example.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_session_cache shared:le_nginx_SSL:1m; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_session_timeout 1440m; # managed by Certbot

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on; # managed by Certbot

    ssl_ciphers "ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384 ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256 ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384 ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384 ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256 ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384 DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384 DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256 DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256 EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA"; # managed by Certbot

   ssl_dhparam /etc/ssl/certs/dhparam.pem;
}
```

I would like http2 enabled for it.

Every doc I've seen says I only need to add "http2" after "ssl": `listen 443 ssl;`, and if I do that nginx happily restart with no error.

I wanted to try if it was working, and couldn't find the protocol in chrome network console anymore. So I found https://tools.keycdn.com/http2-test, which said it worked.

So my questions:

1 - How can I see in chrome (if possible, another if not) if a connection is done over http2 ?

2 - Do I still only need to add the "http2" directive to enable it in my vhost after ssl ? So I do not need to add it to my non-ssl / listen on port 80 line, as that case will be automatically handled between the browser and server during the request, right ?

I don't have any errors or anything, I just wonder how to check that it uses http2 when it can and things work as they should ...

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You have a few things not quite right. A server block can't be listening on port 80 and 443 at the same time. Nowhere do you have anything that tells the server to use http/2 either. You are also redirecting port 80 to port 80 in the first block.

Here's the start of mine:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name mine.com www.mine.com;
    root /var/empty;
    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    server_name  mine.com www.mine.com;
    root /home/mine;
    index index.html;
    charset utf-8;
```

Notice that the first block redirects to https and the second only listens on port 443 as http2.

Note: Your comments gives credit to certbot for a lot of things but certbot doesn't manage anything. It's only a script that gets you certs from LetsEncrypt and that's all. It doesn't "manage" anything beyond that.

EDIT: How can you tell it's working? You should have a green lock in the address bar on the left side. I've been using Firefox mostly because I had a problem with my Chrome install and I noticed I couldn't find the full information in the Chrome dev tools about the protocol. In Firefox it's under networking and listed clearly as 'http2'.

Comment: Certbot using the nginx plugin edits your nginx config files automatically (add the challenge, remove it, add the ssl lines afterwards). That's where those lines come from.

Comment: @user933740 Unless your OS does something completely different from mine, or certbot just works differently, certbot does not edit nginx config files.

Comment: https://certbot.eff.org/docs/using.html#nginx (used with `certbot --nginx`) Is a plugin specifically made for that. It's pretty much `certbot --webroot` + editing the config files automatically.

Comment: Oh and you can get nginx to listen on multiple port, using one port per directive: https://serverfault.com/questions/655067/is-it-possible-to-make-nginx-listen-to-different-ports . My first server block is not to handle port 80 but to redirect example.com to its www subdomain.

Comment: One can have a single virtual host listen to both ports 80 and 443, there isn't nothing that prevents it in principle. However, the preferred way is to have http -> https redirect, and then you need separate virtual hosts for optimal operation.

Comment: Yes, you can listen on multiple ports but you are wanting to redirect 80 to 443 so you can't listen on 80 and redirect to 80 again but I see, now, that you had two server names.

Comment: About certbot: I had forgotten that it now comes with the auto configure thing but it shows how long we've been using LetsEncrypt and certbot. I won't use that since our server set up can be intense so we manually enter what's needed.

Answer (score 0):

> 1 - How can I see in chrome (if possible, another if not) if a
>   connection is done over http2 ?

In chrome, you can do it in the developer tools, in the "network" tab. However, by default, the protocol is not showed: you need to right click on one of the column name and select "protocol".

> 2 - Do I still only need to add the "http2" directive to enable it in
>   my vhost after ssl ? So I do not need to add it to my non-ssl / listen
>   on port 80 line, as that case will be automatically handled between
>   the browser and server during the request, right ?

You are right, you only have to add the "http2" directive after the ssl line, as a non-secure request is redirected to a secure one using HTTP/2.

Comment: "as a non-secure request is redirected to a secure one using HTTP/2.": Could you cite a source for this?

Comment: From the nginx directives present in the author's question. (Here I call a secure request a request redirected to use SSL).