# Nginx: how to proxy pass to same server from different servername:port pairs?

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

I want to reverse proxy like this:

foo.bar.com:3000 -> localhost:4000
bar.foo.com:8080 -> localhost:4000

I think if this is possible, it might look something like this:

```
server {
  listen 3000
  server_name foo.bar.com

  listen 8080
  server_name bar.foo.com

  proxy_pass localhost:4000
  #A lot more configuration
}
```

I know I can just create two `server` directives, each listens on a different `port` with different `server_name` but both `proxy_pass` to localhost:4000.

The problem with this approach is that: redundancy of configuration for each `server` directive. (The configuration is duplicated - one for each `server` directive).

Answer (score 1):

You can add multiple [listen](https://serverfault.com/a/755791/505837) directives and multiple hostnames in [server_name](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html):

```
server {
    listen 3000;
    listen 8080;
    server_name foo.bar.com bar.foo.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:4000;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. But I only want to serve this server with exactly two pairs of server_name:port only, namely `port foo.bar.com:3000` and `bar.foo.com:8080`. Your configuration will serve this server on 4 pairs: `bar.foo.com:8080`, `bar.foo.com:3000` and `foo.bar.com:3000`, `foo.bar.com:8080`.

Comment: Then you will probably have to use two `server`s with or without `include`s.